# Smooth scroll function glitches when a large parameter is used

Tags: javascript, scroll

I wrote a function that will smoothly scroll the screen to the point `dest` pixels.  The problem is that whenever a scroll destination (dest) greater than the total height of the `<body>` is selected, the scrolling never stops, even upon reaching the end of the `<body>` (try scrolling up after the scrolling 'stops').

```
function scroll(dest) {
  var x, scrollDist;
  if(dest > document.body.offsetHeight) {
    dest = document.body.offsetHeight;
  }
  console.log(document.body.offsetHeight);
  console.log(dest);
  x = setInterval(function() {
    // Calculate the scroll distance
    scrollDist = dest - window.scrollY;
    // Log the scroll distance at each iteration
    console.log(scrollDist);

    // If the scroll distance is greater than 10, scroll down 10px, otherwise
    // scroll down by an amount equal to scrollDist then stop scrolling
    if(Math.abs(scrollDist) >= 10) {
      // If the scroll distance is positive scroll down, otherwise scroll up
      if(scrollDist > 0) {
        window.scrollBy(0,2);
      } else {
        window.scrollBy(0,-2);
      }
    } else {
      window.scrollBy(0,scrollDist);
      clearInterval(x);
    }
  },1);
}
scroll(10000);
```

Try it on this webpage or any other webpage with a body height less than 10000px. By looking into the console you can notice that after the end of the body is reached, scrollDist keeps on being logged as 410, which is the weirdest part. Why though? I can't see anything wrong with the algorithm.

Comment: When copied from this page and pasted into the console, your code actually printed 341 to the console over and over again. It seems perfectly obvious that the problem lies in the way that scrollDist is calculated. If the requested dest is too large, you alter it to be the offsetHeight of the document - clearly, this appears to be the wrong value to use.....

Comment: If this is the wrong value (which I can't understand why), what is the correct one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Subtract the page height from the dest variable

As your code stands, the code calculates the position to scroll from with `window.scrollY` which is the height that the top of the window is at. This means that if you try it with a value greater than the page height, it tries to reach 0 scroll distance from the bottom of the page but it doesn't take into account the height of the window. The value that it can't scroll past, which in your case is 410 px, is the window height.

You can fix your code by subtracting `window.innerHeight` from the body's offset height if the scroll distance is too long.

The block in question should be changed from this:

```js
if (dest > document.body.offsetHeight) {  
  dest = document.body.offsetHeight;  
}
```

To this:

```js
if (dest > document.body.offsetHeight) {  
  dest = document.body.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight;  
}
```